# resolv.conf only to be editable by root

Tags: resolv.conf

What should I do to make `/etc/resolv.conf` only editable by root? I don't want anything to edit it after I specify my own DNS servers, i.e. only editable by the user with root privileges.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is already so.

If you mean you want NetworkManager do not overwrite `resolv.conf` you should consider declaring your nameservers in NetworkManager, rather than writing them in `resolv.conf`.

To this aim, it is enough to go to IPv4 page of the connection and set the method to "Automatic (DHCP) address only", or "Manual" if you want to set also a static IP address.